# Python re.findall without lookarounds and not multiline mode (AND NOT SPLIT()) to capture everything besides specified string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, multiline

Key to this problem is making sure to use re.findall NOT using lookarounds and not in multiline mode. This is partially because I also want to port it to use with regex libraries that don't support lookarounds.

Say I have the string below:

```
>>> a = '''bleh blee BLOO
GOO ruu bum LUM Tum
sss ddf GHH rty

[[[BREAK]]]

gumpty RUMPTY BOBBY 
JOE low blow

[[[BREAK]]]

BEEP boop bob
yellow green tam nim
reese yob

[[[BREAK]]]

'''
```

What I want to do is use re.findall to capture everything that is not "\n\n\[\[\[BREAK\]\]\]\n\n" without using lookarounds nor in multiline mode and yes I want the double \n's to be part of the excluded string.

The desired **OUTPUT** is as follows:

```
>>> b[0]
'bleh blee BLOO\nGOO ruu bum LUM Tum\nsss ddf GHH rty'
>>> b[1]
'gumpty RUMPTY BOBBY\nJOE low blow'
>>> b[2]
'BEEP boop bob\nyellow green tam nim\nreese yob'
```

I'm well aware that I can use split() and re.split(), but I want to get a more pure understanding of how to properly write the regex for this because I'm sure it will come up in the future.

```
.
```

*What's grinding my gears is that even in terms of lookarounds I'm having a problem doing this without **cheating** -- below I'm telling it to capture every character string that doesn't contain a "\[" before my ignored string, but that doesn't account for the possibility that "\[" may be present:*

```
>>> b = re.findall('[^\[]+(?=\n\n\[\[\[BREAK\]\]\]\n\n)', a)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> b[0]
'bleh blee BLOO\nGOO ruu bum LUM Tum\nsss ddf GHH rty'
>>> b[1]
'gumpty RUMPTY BOBBY\nJOE low blow'
>>> b[2]
'BEEP boop bob\nyellow green tam nim\nreese yob'
```

Can anyone provide insight? Actually, even an improvement on my lookaround portion may be invited in order to give me a better understanding of that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think you can do it this way.
`(?:^(?:\n\n\[\[\[BREAK\]\]\]\n\n)+)?([\S\s]*?)(?:(?:\n\n\[\[\[BREAK\]\]\]\n\n)+|$)`

You have to match the stuff you don't want in order to move the current position
*past* it. That's just the way it is.

Expanded

```
 (?:
      ^
      (?: \n\n \[\[\[BREAK\]\]\] \n\n )+
 )?
 ( [\S\s]*? )                  # (1)
 (?:
      (?: \n\n \[\[\[BREAK\]\]\] \n\n )+
   |  $ 
 )
```

Comment: This was incredibly close. And is actually putting me on the right track. I'm going to go in depth trying to dissect this. Thank you so much.
The OUTPUT I received from this thus far is ==>>   --------------- b[0] = 'bleh blee BLOO\nGOO ruu bum LUM Tum\nsss ddf GHH rty'      AND    b[1] = 'BEEP boop bob\nyellow green tam nim\nreese yob' ----------  It's so close I can almost taste it so I'm gonna play with it to see if I can grab the last bit. Thanks os much.

Comment: @FailSafe - Oh I'm sorry. Just make the first one optional. See my latest code.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY!!! Dude you are the absolute best!! I'm going to really sit down and try to learn regex on this level cause I don't completely understand it yet. Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! Time to try to figure this this out. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Could I also ask you a quick question. What exactly is ([\S\s]*?) saying by the way? ([\S\s]*) by itself is greedy, but what is the ending "?" saying that disallows the greediness? Thanks so much.

Comment: @FailSafe - Sure. `[\S\s]` is a character class saying `not whitespace or, whitespace`, essentially matches all characters. The `*` is a zero or more greedy quantifier. The `*?` is the same but the ? qualifies it to make it _un-greedy_. This is needed in this case because we _don't_ want to let `[\S\s]` match _past_ the `[[BREAK]]` word.

Comment: Ahhh, so it's a directive that you mightn't see in Python's regex documentation. That's interesting. Alright, definitely learned something new here. Man, I absolutely appreciate your help. This reminds me of when I discovered re.findall('(?:[\S\ ]+\n)+') and how including the "?:"  and the "+" outside of the capture group can lead to 'good' captures of recursions. I use the above whenever I need to capture strings between "two escape characters" while ignoring when there is "one". Is there reliable documentation (with examples) I can read to find these hidden directives? Thanks bunches man.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn regular expression then please take a look at others' posts. If you want to get the job done, `str.split()` is simpler:

```
In [1]: a = '''bleh blee BLOO
   ...: GOO ruu bum LUM Tum
   ...: sss ddf GHH rty
   ...: 
   ...: [[[BREAK]]]
   ...: 
   ...: gumpty RUMPTY BOBBY 
   ...: JOE low blow
   ...: 
   ...: [[[BREAK]]]
   ...: 
   ...: BEEP boop bob
   ...: yellow green tam nim
   ...: reese yob
   ...: 
   ...: [[[BREAK]]]
   ...: 
   ...: '''

In [2]: a.split('[[[BREAK]]]')
Out[2]: 
['bleh blee BLOO\nGOO ruu bum LUM Tum\nsss ddf GHH rty\n\n',
 '\n\ngumpty RUMPTY BOBBY \nJOE low blow\n\n',
 '\n\nBEEP boop bob\nyellow green tam nim\nreese yob\n\n',
 '\n\n']

In [3]: [block.strip() for block in a.split('[[[BREAK]]]')]
Out[3]: 
['bleh blee BLOO\nGOO ruu bum LUM Tum\nsss ddf GHH rty',
 'gumpty RUMPTY BOBBY \nJOE low blow',
 'BEEP boop bob\nyellow green tam nim\nreese yob',
 '']
```

In line 2, we almost got what we want, the next steps (step 3) is to strip the trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy:

```
(.+?)
\[{3}BREAK\]{3}
```

... with `DOTALL` mode, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cOcU5i/1/). If `DOTALL` is not supported, you could change it to `[\s\S]`. `\s` means all whitespaces, while `\S` means all non-whitespace characters. `[..]` is a character class, so if you put `\s` and `\S` in it, you'll end up having **all characters**. After every expression comes a quantifier, in this case the so called *lazy quantifier*: it tries to stop on every occasion unless it feels compelled to further expand due to a following expression. In this case, it only stops when it finds `[[[BREAK]]]` immediately afterwards (thus it is comparable to a lookahead but *consumes* characters instead of just asserting a specific position).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'(.+?)\[{3}BREAK\]{3}', re.DOTALL)
matches = [match.group(1).strip() for match in rx.finditer(a)]
print(matches)
# ['bleh blee BLOO\nGOO ruu bum LUM Tum\nsss ddf GHH rty', 'gumpty RUMPTY BOBBY \nJOE low blow', 'BEEP boop bob\nyellow green tam nim\nreese yob']
```

Comment: This is a great post. Thanks so much. I should have clarified, though, that by multiline mode exclusion I wanted to exclude DOTALL as well. Still, this definitely solved the puzzle, but I'll look into how to do it without specific modes so that I can port it to some other less friendly languages as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @FailSafe: As mentionned in the post, you can use `([\s\S]?)` instead.

Comment: I should also have clarified, I used re.findall('([\s\S]?)\[{3}BREAK\]{3}', a)received =====> b =  ['\n', '\n', '\n'] ------------------ I also used my usual  re.findall('([\s\S]+)\[{3}BREAK\]{3}', a) which gets frustratingly greedy an gives me =====> b = ['bleh blee BLOO\nGOO ruu bum LUM Tum\nsss ddf GHH rty\n\n[[[BREAK]]]\n\ngumpty RUMPTY BOBBY \nJOE low blow\n\n[[[BREAK]]]\n\nBEEP boop bob\nyellow green tam nim\nreese yob\n\n'] ----------------- That's what's making me scratch my eyes out.

Comment: Bro, I see what you're saying. This is GREAT!!! Instead of ([\s\S]?) I think you meant I could have used ([\s\S]*?). That's amazing!!! Could you explain what ([\s\S]*?) means? Please edit your post to reflect this capture so i can give it a check so future users can it. Thank so mcuh dude.

Comment: @FailSafe: Glad to help. Have edited the answer to have more explanatory words.

Comment: My fault. Yet again I should have clarified. What I mean is that for some reason ([\s\S]*) by itself is greedy, but ([\s\S]*?) is not. I was wondering what it is that makes ([\s\S]*?) specifically "\*?" as opposed to just "*" less greedy? Thanks for the longer explanation. I know what [\s\S] means and am a bit more experienced with regex than my post may let on although I'm not an expert. Thanks for your future, further clarification.

Comment: @FailSafe: I did but please have a look on a book on regular expressions or start with the best site on the very same topic: **https://rexegg.com**.

Comment: Ah that explains a lot. I'll definitely take a looksee. Thanks so much brother.